# How to prove ~~A,A→B⊢B without double negation elimination

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is an exercise from *Mathematical Logic: A First Course* by Joel W. Robbin.

> The formal language PI, is obtained from the formal language P by deleting ⊥ from the set of primitive symbols and deleting rule (W2) (which says that ⊥ is a wff) in the definition of wff. The axiom schemas for PI are A$\rightarrow$[B$\rightarrow$A], [A$\rightarrow$[B$\rightarrow$C]]$\rightarrow$[[A$\rightarrow$B]$\rightarrow$[A$\rightarrow$C]], and [[A$\rightarrow$B]$\rightarrow$A]$\rightarrow$A (Peirce’s law), and the rule of inference of PI is $modus\;
> ponens$. The definitions of deduction in PI, deduction from hypotheses in PI,
> and theorem of P, are $mutatis\;mutandis$ the same as for P. The notation $\vdash_\mbox I$ A
> means A is a theorem of PI, and QA is an abbreviation for [A$\rightarrow$Q], In unabbreviating an expression which uses this abbreviation more than once use
> association to the right; that is, QQA stands for QA$\rightarrow$Q rather than A$\rightarrow$QQ. Notice that the wff QA behaves very much like the wff ~A:=A$\rightarrow\bot$.
>
> Show that the deduction theorem holds for P, and prove the following
> theorem schemas.
>
> (1) $\vdash_\mbox I[\mbox A\rightarrow \mbox B]\rightarrow[[\mbox B\rightarrow \mbox C]\rightarrow[\mbox A\rightarrow\mbox C]]$
>
> (2) $\vdash_\mbox I[\mbox A\rightarrow\mbox B]\rightarrow[\mbox{QB}\rightarrow\mbox{QA}]$
>
> (3) $\vdash_\mbox I\mbox A\rightarrow\mbox{QQA}$
>
> (4) $\vdash_\mbox I\mbox{QQQA}\rightarrow\mbox{QA}$
>
> (5) $\vdash_\mbox I\mbox{QQB}\rightarrow\mbox{QQ[A}\rightarrow\mbox B]$
>
> (6) $\vdash_\mbox I\mbox{QQA}\rightarrow[\mbox{QB}\rightarrow\mbox{Q[A}\rightarrow\mbox B]]$
>
> ...

I am now stuck at (6). Using the deduction theorm, I can convert (6) into $\mbox{QQA}\vdash_\mbox I\mbox{QB}\rightarrow\mbox{Q[A}\rightarrow\mbox B]$ and further into $\mbox{QQA}\vdash_\mbox I[\mbox A\rightarrow\mbox B]\rightarrow\mbox B$ by (2) and *modus ponens*. But I don't know how to proceed without double negation elimination to deal with that QQA.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The Double Negation Elimination is typically a straightforward consequence of the Duns Scotus Law $\neg \phi \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$ and the Law of Clavius $(\neg \phi \rightarrow \phi) \rightarrow \phi$. Can you prove those? Because then fill in $\neg \neg A$ for $\phi$ and $A$ for $\psi$ in the Duns Scotus Law, fill in $A$ for $\phi$ in the Law of Clavius, and use your principle 1 to do the Hypothetical Syllogism on these.

Comment: I don't think QQA→A can be proved in this setting. Q is a metavariable which can be replaced by any proposition. It is only a crippled surrogate for ⊥.

Comment: (6) is provable without pierces law, it isn't a short proof though.  I'll work on writing it up...

Comment: The short answer to your question is :
$$\lambda xyz~.~x(\lambda v.y(zv))$$
$$\begin{array} {c|l} \text{variable} & \text{type} \\ \hline
x & ((A \to Q) \to Q \\
y & B \to Q \\
z & A \to B \\
v & A
\end{array}$$

is a well typed simply typed lambda expression, the entire type of which is $((A \to Q) \to Q) \to (B \to Q) \to (A \to B) \to Q$.  So (6) is provable using only the first 2 axioms listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can show you how to solve (6) using type theory.

> (6) $$((A \to Q) \to Q) \to (B \to Q) \to (A \to B) \to Q$$

Proving this is equivalent to finding a lambda expression available with the above type. (You can assume the existance of an expression of the type $(((g \to h) \to g) \to g$, but that is fortunately not necessary in this case).  By trial and error, an expression can be found:

$$\lambda xyz~.~x(\lambda v.y(zv)) \tag{P1a}$$
$$\begin{array} {c|l} \text{variable} & \text{type} \\ \hline
x & ((A \to Q) \to Q \\
y & B \to Q \\
z & A \to B \\
v & A
\end{array} \tag{P1b}$$

This allows you to construct a proof if you have deduction theorem available:

$$\begin{array} {r|ll}
%
(1) & ((A \to Q) \to Q) & \text{Premise} \\
%
(2) & B \to Q & \text{Premise} \\
%
(3) & A \to B & \text{Premise} \\
%
(4) & A & \text{Premise} \\
%
(5) & B & \text{Modus Ponens 3 , 4} \\
%
(6) & Q & \text{Modus Ponens 2 , 5} \\
%
(7) & A \to Q & \text{Deduction theorem on 6 removing premise 4} \\
%
(8) & Q & \text{Modus Ponens 1 , 7} \\
%
(9) & (A \to B) \to Q & \text{Deduction theorem on 8 removing premise 3} \\
%
(10) & (B \to Q) \to (A \to B) \to Q & \text{Deduction theorem on 9 removing premise 2} \\
%
(11) & ((A \to Q) \to Q) \to (B \to Q) \to (A \to B) \to Q & \text{Deduction theorem on 10 removing premise 1} \\
%
\end{array}$$

And if you don't have the deduction theorem immediately available, then the proof is very very long.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is one thing I don't understand. You seem to claim that type A is inhabited, which isn't assumed by the exercise and this is exactly where I'm stuck in. If QQA->A were available, I could prove A with QQA, but there is no double negation elimination.

Comment: The conclusion doesn't depend on A being provable.  That's the entire point of the deduction theorem.  The premise of A is removed in step 7.

Comment: With respect to the "very very long" comment, I fired up Prover9 and in less than 10 seconds, it found a proof that has only 14 condensed detachments.  Though, it indicated a proof of the more general CCCxyzCCuyCCxuz.

Answer (score 0):

QQA stands for [QA -> Q].  QA is an abbreviation for [A -> Q].  Thus,

QQA stands for [[A -> Q] -> Q], correct?

So, if you expand out (6), without the meta-logical $\vdash$$_I$, you end up with (and add some points for emphasis) the following

[.[[A -> Q] -> Q]. -> [:[B -> Q]: -> [;[A -> B]; -> Q]]], correct?

Thus, assume

1. [[A -> Q] -> Q].  Then assume
2. [B -> Q].  Then assume
3. [A -> B]

Now, can you deduce Q?

Comment: If QQA→A were available, I could use modus ponens to produce Q. But the only QQA related thing I have now is (5)QQA→QQ[B→A]. I can't see how this makes way to Q.